# Observable not referencing interface while returning data

Tags: angular, typescript

So i am making a management system project in which I am trying to receive data from backend. I made a service class and the returned observable is passed to another component just fine. Now when I am trying to make a interface to only receive the data that I specify in the interface, the observable is not referencing it. What I mean to say is that the data returned is an object but even passing any data type like `number[]` in observable return type works. I am not finding the problem here please help.
I am adding some code and output for reference.

homeComponent.ts

```
import { AssetDetailService } from '../asset-detail.service';

constructor(private _assetDetailService:AssetDetailService) { }
 ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
    if(id!=null)
    this._assetDetailService.getSingleAssetData(id).subscribe(data=>console.log(data));
```

asset-detail.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { IAssetDetail } from './asset-detail';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AssetDetailService {
  private _url:string="http://localhost:25160/api/assets";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getSingleAssetData(id:string):Observable<IAssetDetail>{
    let modifiedUrl = `${this._url}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<IAssetDetail>(modifiedUrl);
  }
}
```

asset-detail.ts Interface

```
export interface IAssetDetail {
    projectName:string,
    assetCategory:string,
    manufacturer:string,
    assetName:string,
    description:string,
    mlfb:string,
    workingCondition:string,
    remark:string 
}
```

Output that I am receiving

```
category: "category 1"
currentUserEmail: "abc@hello.com"
description: "Asset Description"
id: "68eb6877-0bf0-45fb-bdf9-d84fb9ec889f"
invoiceNumber: "2989"
invoiceReceiveDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
ipAddress: "Asset IP Address"
location: "Asset Name"
manufacturer: "Asset Manufacturer"
mlfb: "Asset Mlfb"
name: "Asset Name"
owner: "ABC"
poNumber: "2823"
projectName: "projectId"
remarks: "remarks"
serialNumber: 8796
supportComm: "Asset Support"
workingCondition: "Yes"
```

As you can see  most of the variables defined in interface are not matching the output but the app is still working . I am neither receiving any error for not declaring a variable in interface nor getting the desired result.
Please ask if you have any doubts regarding the question i will try my best to explain.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`interfaces` in Typescript are blueprints for data. They are sort of guidelines not **rules** for how your data should come.

Ultimately your code gets transpiled to `javascript` which has no knowledge about interfaces. So any extra fields your backend might be returning will not be filtered from the response.

Interfaces are TS feature to make features like autocomplete work.
If you want to remove unwanted data, use `map` operator

```
getSingleAssetData(id:string):Observable<IAssetDetail>{
    let modifiedUrl = `${this._url}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<IAssetDetail>(modifiedUrl).pipe(map(data=>{
        return {
          projectName: data.projectName,
          assetCategory: data.assetCategory,
          manufacturer: data.manufacturer,
          assetName: data.assetName,
          description: data.description,
          mlfb: data.mlfb,
          workingCondition: data.workingCondition,
          remark: data.remark,
       }
     }));

  }
```

Comment: I tried the same thing as i mentioned in the question in another project and there it is working as expected like giving error for variables not being defined in interface and observable returning the data that are mentioned in interface but i am not seeing the problem here. why?

Comment: IMHO you might be using a 3rd party package to enforce schema there. Without any class or manual intervention(as I showed above with `map`) JS won't enforce any schema.  An interface is purely a TypeScript construct, it doesn't exist in JavaScript and is not emulated in any way

Comment: No i am not using any third party package there also. https://youtu.be/LmIsbzt-S_E this is the reference for second project.

Comment: From angular documentation(https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response):

Specifying the response type is a declaration to TypeScript that it should treat your response as being of the given type. This is a build-time check and doesn't guarantee that the server will actually respond with an object of this type. It is up to the server to ensure that the type specified by the server API is returned.

Comment: Unless you make explicit access to your missingProperty with `data.missingProperty` in your service. JS does not have any problem with your server throwing extra or less variables in response.